# Execute Javascript function from GridView ItemTemplate button click ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a DataGridView that has two ItemTemplate button columns that are dynamically generated. I have code-behind for the both of the buttons that fire when they are clicked, but I also need a javascript function to run when the btnInfo button is clicked

markup:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gridResutls" runat="server" OnRowCommand="gridResutls_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="strName" HeaderText="Name"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="strBrand" HeaderText="Brand"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="strServing" HeaderText="Serving"/>
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnInfo" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="MoreInfo"
                            Text="More Info" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("strID") %>'/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="AddItem"
                            Text="Add To Log" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("strID") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>'
```

I have a javascript function called `populateLabel()` that I need to fire off when btnInfo is clicked.

Any ideas? (I know similar questions have been asked and I looked throughout the posts and tried a few things but nothing seems to work)

EDIT: Here is what the code-behind for the ItemTemplate buttons looks like

```
protected void gridResutls_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        // Kick out if neither of the two dynamically created buttons have been clicked
        if (e.CommandName != "MoreInfo" && e.CommandName != "AddItem")
        {
            return;
        }

        // If the "More Info" buton has been clicked
        if (e.CommandName == "MoreInfo")
        {
             // Some code
        }

        // If the "Add To Log" button has been clicked
        if (e.CommandName == "AddItem")
        {
            // Some code
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {    
            Button btnAdd = e.Row.FindControl("btnAdd") as Button;
            btnAdd.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "populateLabel();");
        }
    }
```

markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function populateLabel() {
        alert('hi');
    }

</script>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="DSModels" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnInfo" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="MoreInfo"
                    Text="More Info" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="AddItem"
                    Text="Add To Log" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Nah that doesn't do it

Comment: It seems to be working. I have built and run a sample app. Please see the updated answer

Comment: You're right it does work. Thank you. The label i have generating in the javascript function pops up for a second then disappears. Does it need to be wrapped in a document.ready?

Answer (score 1):

Use `OnClientClick`:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnInfo" runat="server" OnClientClick="populateLabel()" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="MoreInfo"
  Text="More Info" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("strID") %>'/>
```

[**Example here.**](http://forums.asp.net/t/1879546.aspx)

Comment: OnClientClck doesn't work for some reason. I tried that already.

Comment: What your javascript function does ? Add it to your question.

Comment: Populates a nutrition label using a jquery function that comes from an API. I put a breakpoint on the first line of the function and tried a bunch of different things but it wasnt getting hit

Comment: It does recognize populateLabel in the intellisense when i use the OnClientClick though

Comment: Look at your source what is the html that the page is generating for the button with the OnClientClick set?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that

Comment: You're correct, there is a problem with the javascript function i am calling. I used an alert("test") the the onclientclick and it worked just fine. Thank you.