# How to trigger a click event programmatically on a link button inside Gridview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

Is there a way to trigger a link button inside a gridview via javascript or jquery? Something like...

```
document.getElementById('<%= lnkEdit.ClientID %>').click();
```

lnkEdit being the link button inside GridView1. I want to trigger it programmatically instead of physically clicking the link button. The index of the row will be 0; the grid returns only one row...

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder could you explain me how to trigger a click event server side please?

Comment: in the link you posted, you simply call server side the same function associated to the click. This doesn't mean absolutely to "trigger a click event server side". This only means that inside a function you call another function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868454/execute-javascript-function-from-gridview-itemtemplate-button-click-asp-net-web

Comment: @Jayakrishnan Gounder I would like to trigger the event at client-side; by javascript or jquery

Comment: What is going to decide when you want this trigger to occur? Whenever that happens, just call the function that handles the click event. If the handler is completely reliant on the 'this' keyword this article explains how to trigger and event from a DOM element. http://2ality.com/2013/06/triggering-events.html